# Autotesting application written on Qt with Python

Tags: python, c++, qt, automated-tests

I want to test application written on Qt by Python.
Workflow that I want:
1. Python script should run .exe
2. Python script should get/set info from/into active window.

Is it possible to manipulate Qt window if I know "object name" (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop)?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a method of communication between the Python test and the program.

For example the program could read commands from STDIN or a socket when being started in a test mode and the test would write to that.

Depending on the platform it might also be possible to expose objects via a remote procedure calling mechanism, e.g. D-Bus (using QtDBus on the program side and Pythons D-Bus bindings on the test side).

Ultimately it might be better though to consider using an existing test suite with Qt support, such as [Squish](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/) or [AutoPilot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Testing/Autopilot)